# call to free() crashes with 'invalid pointer'

Tags: c, free

I am writing a program to parse a dictionary text file (the [cedict](https://cc-cedict.org/wiki/format:syntax) dictionary, to be exact) and insert all rows into a sqlite3 database. I created a struct representing the dictionary entry:

```
typedef struct {
    char *      traditional;
    char *      simplified;
    char *      pinyin;
    char *      english;
} entry_t;
```

I am parsing the line and storing the strings (which were created using a malloc statement) in the struct, and at the end of my while loop to read all of the lines in the file I free the memory that was allocated. This works for more than 99% of the lines in the file, however on the 1137th line the call to free fails with code 134 and message 'invalid pointer'. My first thought was that I wrote to a memory address outside of the malloc'd block of memory, but after double checking that doesn't seem to be the case. If I increase the size of my malloc'd string to hold that value, it fails on a different line instead. I also tried analyzing it in Valgrind, but was not entirely sure what the output meant, but I did see that it only failed 3 times on the 116,000 lines. Not sure what is going on here.

```
while(-1 != getline(line, size, fid)) {
    clear(entry);
    indices[0] = *line;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < sizeof(indices) / sizeof(char *); i++) {
        indices[i] = strchr(indices[i - 1], search [i - 1]);
    }
    entry->traditional = malloc(indices[1] - indices[0] + 1);
    memcpy(entry->traditional, indices[0], indices[1] - indices[0]);
    entry->traditional[indices[1] - indices[0]] = '\0';

    entry->simplified = malloc(indices[2] - indices[1] - 2);
    memcpy(entry->simplified, indices[1] + 1, indices[2] - indices[1] - 2);
    entry->simplified[indices[2] - indices[1] - 2] = '\0';

    entry->pinyin = malloc(indices[3] - indices[2] - 1);
    memcpy(entry->pinyin, indices[2] + 1, indices[3] - indices[2] - 1);
    entry->pinyin[indices[3] - indices[2] - 1] = '\0';

    entry->english = malloc(strlen(indices[4]) - 1);
    memcpy(entry->english, indices[4], strlen(indices[4]) - 2);
    entry->english[strlen(indices[4]) - 2] = '\0';

    sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 1, ++id);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, entry->traditional, -1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, entry->simplified, -1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, entry->pinyin, -1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, entry->english, -1, NULL);

    while (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(stmt));
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);

    free(entry->traditional);
    free(entry->simplified);
    free(entry->pinyin);
    free(entry->english);     // <---- this is where it crashes
    printf("inserted: %lld items\n", id);
}
```

In this code, clear is a macro for memset(entry, 0, sizeof(*entry)) and the indices array contains pointers to specific positions that help in parsing. Also, any other constructive criticisms of my code would be appreciated.

Edit: Valgrind output. Currently waiting on the program to finish running in Valgrind (30 ish minutes total), but I noticed that there is some output at the top that I had missed because of printfs before. It is below

```
==5629== Invalid write of size 1
==5629==    at 0x1090AD: main (main.c:74)
==5629==  Address 0x5d28291 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==5629==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5629==    by 0x10904E: main (main.c:72)
==5629== 
==5629== Invalid write of size 1
==5629==    at 0x10912B: main (main.c:78)
==5629==  Address 0x5d282e3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==5629==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5629==    by 0x1090CC: main (main.c:76)
==5629== 
==5629== Invalid read of size 1
==5629==    at 0x4C32D04: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5629==    by 0x4E792DA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
==5629==    by 0x4E89148: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
==5629==    by 0x1091FF: main (main.c:86)
==5629==  Address 0x5d28291 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==5629==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5629==    by 0x10904E: main (main.c:72)
==5629== 
==5629== Invalid read of size 1
==5629==    at 0x4C32D04: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5629==    by 0x4E792DA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
==5629==    by 0x4E89148: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6)
==5629==    by 0x109226: main (main.c:87)
==5629==  Address 0x5d282e3 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==5629==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5629==    by 0x1090CC: main (main.c:76)
```

Comment: You have either corrupted something on the stack or the heap.  Please post the valgrind output.  Nobody here is going to be able to debug your program with a snippet of code.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me `clear(entry);` does the same memory freeing you're already doing at the tail of this loop.  that is a recipe for double-freeing, which will serve up *undefined behavior* rather nicely. Related, things like `malloc(strlen(s) - n)` is a recipe for disaster. Think about what happen when `s` is a terminated string *shorter* than `n`. Then actually test it with a simple sample program. It will probably surprise you.

Comment: Try to check if all indexes in arrays are nonnegative - `#include <assert.h>` or simply `if(index < 0) {/*handle error*/}`. Note, that if `strchr(indices[i - 1], search [i - 1])` cannot find searched char, it will return `NULL` and things could get messy.

Comment: @WhozCraig I would like to respectfully disagree with you - I don't think that clear(entry) is doing the same thing as a call to free() - the struct that is being cleared out only contains pointers to the strings, and it won't actually zero out the memory used by the strings. Additionally, free() tells the OS that the memory is not longer in use and can be overwritten, but memset only sets the value. Also, I happen to know that the value of the string will always be greater than 1 - so not quite an issue in this scenario. Is there an alternative that you would suggest?

Comment: @Przemek the format of the dictionary entries guarantees that the character I am searching for will be found. I will add asserts though just to make sure, and let you know the results

Comment: @GusW Thus my *crystal ball*, and not based on any fact, like say, the source to `clear`, which we don't have, and apparently you don't either. A debugger would probably help, and valgrind certainly would.

Comment: @OldProgrammer updated with Valgrind output - it is currently still running though, will post the results when it finishes

Comment: @WhozCraig in the first line underneath the code I defined what the macro was. Sorry that wasn't clearer. As for the second part of your statement, is there an alternative to malloc(strlen(s) - n) that you would suggest?

Comment: Worth noting that it's bad form to `malloc` without checking the return value for success/failure -- it sets you up for bad problems down the line that are often far more difficult to trace back to that `malloc` than needed.

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks for the suggestion. I will implement that

Comment: The invalid writes in the valgrind post are pretty clear. You under-allocate your `simplified` member by one byte.  If you allocate with `malloc(indices[2] - indices[1] - 2)`, that means `entry->simplified[indices[2] - indices[1] - 2] = '\0';` is out of range (zero based indexing on a sequence of `n` is `0..n-1`. Looks like `pinyin` has the same problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig yep, that seems to have fixed the problem. I've not used Valgrind very much, this was a good learning experience. If you write an answer I will accept it